# Printing a checker board with nested loops. [Java]

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm having issues with getting my code to print. I need to print a checker board with a grid the size of a user input.

Example of what it should output.

```
Input a size (must be larger than 1):
5

0 *   *   *
1   *   *  
2 *   *   *
3   *   *  
4 *   *   *
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class nestedpractice1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbinput = new Scanner(System.in); 
        //Create Size variable
        System.out.println("Input a size: ");
        int n = 0; n = kbinput.nextInt();

        for(int r = 0; r < n; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < r; c++)
                    {
                if((r%2) == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else if((r%1) == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(" *");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
            kbinput.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My code keeps printing

```
**

****
```

Comment: In the future: Please add a description of what error you are getting, or what the current output of your program is, and what you expected instead.

Comment: Please explain what your output should look like and why you think that your code should yield the expected result.

Comment: I have made a few edits to help with my question. I am new to this so I apologize if my post is vague. I'm still trying to learn how to properly form a coding question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop yields precisely the output you specified:

```
    for (int r = 0; r < n; r++) {
        System.out.print(r);
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            System.out.print(r % 2 == 1 ^ c % 2 == 0 ? " *" : "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I condensed the body of the inner loop to a single `print` statement. This statement uses the `^` (xor) operator to test for a condition, and then the `?:` (ternary) operator to print an asterisk if the condition is `true` or spaces if the condition is `false`.

We could break up that single statement, while retaining its meaning, like so:

```
            boolean isOddRow = r % 2 == 1;
            boolean isEvenCol = c % 2 == 0;
            System.out.print(isOddRow ^ isEvenCol ? " *" : "  ");
```

As explanation, we want to print a `*` only if the row and column are both even or both odd. So if the row is even but the column is odd, or if the row is odd but the column even, we print only spaces.

We could express the same logic using `==` instead of `^` by:

```
            boolean isEvenRow = r % 2 == 0;
            boolean isEvenCol = c % 2 == 0;
            System.out.print(isEvenRow == isEvenCol ? " *" : "  ");
```

Or if you prefer the longhand `if..else` over the shorthand ternary operator:

```
            if (isEvenRow == isEvenCol) {
                System.out.print(" *");
            } else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
```

Comment: Thank you. I was having a large amount of trouble with this. I will have to learn more about this (xor) operator and (ternary) operator. I think they will be very handy in the future.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your code, I found these potential issues:

- `kbinput.close();` should not be called inside the loop.
- `else if((r%1) == 0)` should be `else if (r % 2 != 0)`, although in this case simply `else` is enough.
- in the `else`, you might want to do `System.out.print(" ");`
  instead of `System.out.print(" *");`
- I believe `for(int c = 0; c < r; c++) {` should loop as long as `c < n`.